# Просмотр интернет видео в программе

Tags: c#, winforms

Стало интересно, возможно ли сделать плеер который будет отображать фильмы с различных сайтов в виде каталога и при воспроизведении будет отображать фильм, но кнопки управления (пауза, перемотка и т.д.) будут не от сайта, а программные. Может какие примеры или кто-то видел похожее. Если кто-то сталкивался с похожей темой, расскажите с чего начинать и что делать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы вам советовал смотреть в сторону `WPF` для начала. На `WinForms` вам сложно будет кастомизировать контролы...

Comment: а webbrowser чем не подходит?

Comment: WebBrowser будет отображать сайт. Это не нужно. Хочу сделать что-то вроде клиента для онлайн кинотеатров.

Comment: Если эти сайты предоставляют прямые ссылки на фильмы, то нет проблем их использовать (кроме проблем с законом). Размещаем в приложении столько компонентов-видеоплееров, сколько нужно, и воспроизводим сразу кучу фильмов.